# Struggle with SQL Statement (Not Exists)

Tags: sql, elgg, not-exists

Hey i have some problems with a sql statement. This is the Database Scheme:(http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/DatabaseSchema), only the "entities" and the "relationship" table are important! What i'm trying to do is, select all guid's where the type of the object is "group" but this object is not a child of a other group. That means there is no record in the relationship table with the guid in the guid_two column. My first idea was this:

```
SELECT * FROM elgg_entities e 
JOIN elgg_entity_relationships r ON e.guid = r.guid_one
WHERE e.type='group' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM elgg_entity_relationships s 
    WHERE e.guid = s.guid_two 
          AND s.relationship='subgroup')
```

But it wont work. Also there are some other relationships in the table like member etc. I hope someone can help me, because i really frustrated right now.

Edit: This SQL query works in MyPHP, in elgg i tried to convert it into "elgg-ich":

```
$options = array(
    'type' => 'group',
    'joins' => array("JOIN elgg_entity_relationships r ON e.guid = r.guid_one"),
    'wheres' => array("e.type='group' AND not exists (SELECT e.guid
    FROM elgg_entity_relationships s
    where e.guid = s.guid_two
    AND s.relationship = 'subgroup' 
 )"),
 'limit' => $limit,
 'full_view' => FALSE,
 );
$content = elgg_list_entities($options);
```

=> Solution was the case sensitivity and where instead of wheres in line 6.

Comment: Your query looks fine, perhaps you can set up an example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to make the problem tangible

Comment: You are right. I tried the query in php and i recieved the right guidd. Looks like the problem is in elgg. Thanks!

Comment: Please define `wont work`.  Do you get error message?  If so, please show them.  Do you get un-expected results?  If so, please show the input data, the results and why they're not what you expected.

Comment: No i don't get an error and with the debugg mode i can't find anything. Looks for me like elgg just ignore the WHERE part.

Comment: might be case sensitive `WHERE` instead of `where`?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the edited question;

> Solution was the case sensitivity and where instead of wheres in line
>   6.